# Eclipse Dex Loader Error (Multiple dex files define )

Tags: android, eclipse, dex

I am trying to run a game app but  I am getting this error .

```
[2014-07-19 09:18:23 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/Application$ApplicationType;
[2014-07-19 09:18:23 - my-gdx-game-android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/Application$ApplicationType
```

I tried cleaning,refreshing and deleting bin folder.If I delete bin folder it generates again. I tried restarting eclipse. But nothing worked for me. I need you help experts.

Comment: check your Jars. Have you added 2 jars with the same class(es)?

Comment: I tried deleting duplicates but i got the same error.

Comment: How this question is related to Java programming language?

Comment: delete all the jar files and try adding one by one, if you are using library projects make sure both projects dont have the same support library one is enough for both, try that too may be it will solve ur issue